# Moving image icon from one nav menu list item to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

all. This is a follow-up question to a question I asked before. A person answering that question suggested the follow-up as a separate question.

So, I have a page on video that I'm trying to replicate. The page is here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_EvMbZuQ7C7eUpvN1N2OWpldlU. I hope you're able to view it. In the video, at the bottom right of the page, there is a nav menu consisting of Home, About, Schedule and Contact. In the video, the user hovers over Home, and a paw print image/icon comes in from the left side of the screen and rests under Home, pushing the word Home up. Then, when the person hovers over About, the icon moves from Home to About. It does this for every list item when you hover over it.

With help from the previous question, I now have it where the icon comes in from the left and rests under Home. However, when I then hover over About, Schedule, or Contact, the icon disappears from the item it is under and then comes in again from the left of the screen.

Here is my CSS code:

```
li{
            display: inline;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 2vw;
            padding-top: 52vh;
        }
        li span{
            position: relative;
            transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
        }
        li::before{
            content: url("images/pawprint.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            position: absolute;
            transform: translate(100%);
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity /*1s*/ ease-in-out;
        }
        li:hover::before{
            opacity: 1;
            animation: slide 1s;
        }

        li:hover span {
            top: -4vh;
        }
        @keyframes slide{
            from {
                margin-left: -100%;
            }
            to {
                margin-left: 0%;
            }
        }
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<footer>
            <nav id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="orange"><span>Contact</span></li>
                    <li class="orange"><span>Schedule</span></li>
                    <li class="orange"><span>About</span></li>
                    <li class="orange"><span>Home</span></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        </footer>
```

I don't have any jQuery code yet. Haven't figured out if this problem requires jQuery/JavaScript or if it can be done solely with CSS. I'll take either, as long as it works.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I just realized that the video is on a Google Drive that has been shared with me, so I don't know if any of you will be able to see it.  If not, can anyone tell me where I can copy it so you can see it? Is there a way to put it on GitHub? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This has a few glitches but is mostly what you are looking for.

```js
var paw=document.getElementById('paw');
    var lis= document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    window.onload=function(){
        for(var i=0;i<lis.length;i++){
 li=lis[i];
 li.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
     paw.style.left=Math.round(this.getBoundingClientRect().left)+"px";
 });
 li.addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
     paw.style.left="0px";
 });
    }};
```

```css
li {
    display: inline;
 float: right;
 padding-right: 2vw;
 padding-top: 52vh;
}
#paw{
    position:relative;top:52vh;left:0;transition: 1s;
}
li span {
    position: relative;
 transition: top 1s;
}

li:hover span {
 top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="orange"><span>Contact</span></li>
            <li class="orange"><span>Schedule</span></li>
            <li class="orange"><span>About</span></li>
            <li class="orange"><span>Home</span></li>
         </ul>
  </nav>
  <img src="http://auto.ferrari.com/en_EN/wp-content/themes/ferrari-gt/img/logo_ferrari.png" id="paw"/>
</footer>
```